# I require assistance straightening out a rig

Tags: modeling, rigging

this is my first model, so I hope i don't get too much grief for asking such a simple question, but I need to know how to make my low poly rig actually fit my model. I can't exactly describe the entire scope of my project in this forum, so I hope somebody can actually look at my .blend file. I will say though, that some of the issues are:

- the left (technically right) hand mesh of the model moves with the right hand controller, making the hand controller assigned to it useless.
- shoulders narrow down way too much.
- the right (technically left) side of the upper leg and butt does not fit the bone properly.
- the armpits are very flat and narrowed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with the model rigging, but I still have no idea why the left hand mesh is bound to the right hand controller, despite them having no visible relationship, at least not one that i'm aware of.

Comment: For the had I'm not sure why it happens but maybe apply the *Mirror* modifier and parent again (or just correct this part)

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the armature a bit:

- In *Edit* mode, move the knees a bit forwards so that Blender knows in what direction they are supposed to bend:

[image]

- Correct the *Pole Angle* (-90° for the left leg):

[image]

- For the arms, align the pole targets with the elbows, otherwise as soon as you switch to *Pose* mode, the elbows will shift, as they are supposed to point towards them:

[image]

- And same thing, move the elbows a bit backwards and correct the *Pole Angle*:

[image]

For the hand I'm not sure why it happens but maybe apply the *Mirror* modifier and parent again (or just correct this part)